# Cannot Implicitly Convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'

Tags: c#

I have been trying to set up a random number generator that pics a number between 0 and 52 and then change a picture box to the the corresponding picture in an imagelist but i keep getting this error message

> Cannot Implicitly Convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'

```
Random ran = new Random();
int RandomNumber = ran.Next(0, 52);
PicPlayerCard1 = imgCards.Images[RandomNumber];
```

Comment: Last line should be `PicPlayerCard1.Image = imgCards.Images[RandomNumber];`

Answer (score 3):

`PicPlayerCard1` in your code is of type `PictureBox`, not `Image`.

There is a property named [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image) in the class PictureBox, so you should use it:

```
Random ran = new Random();
int RandomNumber = ran.Next(0, 52);
PicPlayerCard1.Image = imgCards.Images[RandomNumber];
```